# Cannot restore LVM metadata because of missing PV device

Tags: linux, hard-drive, lvm

This is a machine running Fedora 28 with one hard drive. I popped in another hard drive to see if could extract data from it (No), but after I removed it (back to one drive) I found that it had messed up the pv and lv data:

```
[root@localhost-live ~]# pvscan
  WARNING: Device for PV F3lvXa-42cI-6Tx2-hmSr-3E0M-0PFE-W7kLj1 not found  or rejected by a filter.
  PV /dev/sda2   VG vg_debussy      lvm2 [931.00 GiB / 0    free]
  PV [unknown]   VG vg_debussy      lvm2 [931.50 GiB / 0    free]
  Total: 2 [<1.82 TiB] / in use: 2 [<1.82 TiB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]

[root@localhost-live ~]# vgscan
  Reading volume groups from cache.
  WARNING: Device for PV F3lvXa-42cI-6Tx2-hmSr-3E0M-0PFE-W7kLj1 not found or rejected by a filter.
  Found volume group "vg_debussy" using metadata type lvm2

[root@localhost-live ~]# lvs
  WARNING: Device for PV F3lvXa-42cI-6Tx2-hmSr-3E0M-0PFE-W7kLj1 not found or rejected by a filter.
  LV      VG         Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  lv_home vg_debussy -wi-----p-   1.75t                                                    
  lv_root vg_debussy -wi-a-----  50.00g                                                    
  lv_swap vg_debussy -wi-ao---- <17.69g                                                    

[root@localhost-live ~]# lvscan
  WARNING: Device for PV F3lvXa-42cI-6Tx2-hmSr-3E0M-0PFE-W7kLj1 not found or rejected by a filter.
  ACTIVE            '/dev/vg_debussy/lv_root' [50.00 GiB] inherit
  inactive          '/dev/vg_debussy/lv_home' [1.75 TiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/vg_debussy/lv_swap' [<17.69 GiB] inherit
```

and I could not activate lv_home

The reason seemed be be a duplicate Physical Volume with the same VG name:

```
[root@localhost-live ~]# pvdisplay
  WARNING: Device for PV F3lvXa-42cI-6Tx2-hmSr-3E0M-0PFE-W7kLj1 not found or rejected by a filter.
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sda2
  VG Name               vg_debussy
  PV Size               931.02 GiB / not usable 24.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               32.00 MiB
  Total PE              29792
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          29792
  PV UUID               KSk5KO-Su5d-H8LO-a8t0-s8gH-WdWA-DXQZTr

  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               [unknown]
  VG Name               vg_debussy
  PV Size               931.51 GiB / not usable 12.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               32.00 MiB
  Total PE              29808
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          29808
  PV UUID               F3lvXa-42cI-6Tx2-hmSr-3E0M-0PFE-W7kLj1
```

So this is where I made my mistake (following what someone else had written that supposedly worked):

```
[root@localhost-live ~]# vgreduce --removemissing --force vg_debussy 
  WARNING: Device for PV F3lvXa-42cI-6Tx2-hmSr-3E0M-0PFE-W7kLj1 not found or rejected by a filter.
  WARNING: Removing partial LV vg_debussy/lv_home.
  Logical volume "lv_home" successfully removed
  Wrote out consistent volume group vg_debussy.

[root@localhost-live ~]# pvdisplay
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sda2
  VG Name               vg_debussy
  PV Size               931.02 GiB / not usable 24.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes 
  PE Size               32.00 MiB
  Total PE              29792
  Free PE               27626
  Allocated PE          2166
  PV UUID               KSk5KO-Su5d-H8LO-a8t0-s8gH-WdWA-DXQZTr

  [root@localhost-live ~]# lvscan
  ACTIVE            '/dev/vg_debussy/lv_root' [50.00 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/vg_debussy/lv_swap' [<17.69 GiB] inherit
```

So I had removed both lv_home - the one on the missing PV and the the one I wanted to keep!

```
[root@localhost-live ~]# vgcfgrestore vg_debussy --test -f /etc/lvm/archive/vg_debussy_00000-611197733.vg
  TEST MODE: Metadata will NOT be updated and volumes will not be (de)activated.
  /dev/cdrom: open failed: No medium found
  Couldn't find device with uuid F3lvXa-42cI-6Tx2-hmSr-3E0M-0PFE-W7kLj1.
  Cannot restore Volume Group vg_debussy with 1 PVs marked as missing.
  Restore failed.
```

So what, if anything can I do now? I'm running this off a live USB.

Comment: I guess it is too late now. You should mount /dev/vg_debussy/lv_root somewhere and access lvm archive from there